# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number for a simple query

Tags: c#, oracle

I am facing this issue for this very simple query. I don't understand the reason behind it.

```
    string strCon=myConnectionString;
    string strSql=string.Format("select * from tblUser where UserName like '{0}%'",":Name");
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(strCon);
    OracleCommand command = null;
    command = new OracleCommand(strSql, conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    //Getting this value from a function it is a string type variable
    val = val.Trim().ToUpper().Replace("'", "''");
    command.Parameters.Add("Name", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = val;
    DataSet dsEmail = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(dsEmail);
```

Comment: What is your `strSql` exactly after added `Name` parameter? And **Select * FORM** ? Also consider to use [parameterized sql](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: Please consider some other way of doing this. Anyone can inject some sql...

Comment: Hey Soner Gönül, Exact Oracle statement is "Select * from tblUser where UserName like ':Rati%'"

Comment: Try changing your SQL to `"select * from tblUser where UserName like ':' || {0} || '%'"`, and change the second parameter to String.Format to `"@Name"`.  Give that a shot and let us know how it goes.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution of my question. I had made a mistake in my query itself it was not correct. The correct syntax was

```
string strSql=string.Format("select * from tblUser where UserName like {0} || '%'",":Name");
```